# is there a reason to use (FileManager)fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: over (URL).hasDirectoryPath?

Tags: objective-c, swift

What is the practical difference between [(FileManager)fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410277-fileexistsatpath?language=objc) and [(URL).hasDirectoryPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780160-hasdirectorypath)?

I'm following some tutorials and they first used the FileManager approach, but then appear to consistently use the URL method afterwards. In my eyes, the URL approach seems more concise and easier to remember. Is there ever any reason to use the FileManager method instead? (and please provide examples if the answer is *yes*)

Comment: Aha! If you want to put the availability answer as an eligilble answer, I will mark it as THE answer.

Comment: There is a very large difference between the two APIs; it is not only availability. I have written a new answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to the accepted answer, the difference is not only availability. The `FileManager` API actually accesses the file pointed to by the `URL` on the disk to see if it is a directory, whereas `hasDirectoryPath` does not; it only checks whether the `URL`'s path has a slash (`/`) at the end of it, which indicates that the path points to a directory. You can verify this by making an app and running it in the File Activity instrument; with `FileManager` you will see an `lstat64` on the directory, whereas with `hasDirectoryPath` you will not.

This has a few effects:

1. `hasDirectoryPath` will obviously perform much faster, since it does not access the disk.
2. However, `hasDirectoryPath` may give incorrect results if the `URL`'s path is incorrect regarding the presence of the trailing slash. For example:

   `URL(string: "file:///usr/bin")!.hasDirectoryPath // evaluates to false
    URL(string: "file:///usr/bin/")!.hasDirectoryPath // evaluates to true`
3. Finally, `hasDirectoryPath` can work on a non-`file:` `URL`, such as an `http:` `URL`, whereas `FileManager` obviously cannot.

With all that said, when you need to check via the file system, it is better to use the `URL`-based mechanism for this rather than path-based ones in `FileManager`:

```
let isDir = (try? self.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]))?.isDirectory ?? false
```

Comment: Your answer is only correct when you use the `URL(string: "file://\(path)")` constructor. `URL(fileURLWithPath: path)` will check if the file the path is pointing to is a directory. `URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin").hasDirectoryPath` returns `true` on my machine.